# How to make schema of postgres sql dynamic in laravel?

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel-5, schema

I need to make schema of postgres dynamic in laravel. The database config is below

```
'pgsql' => [
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'stoddart'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'postgres'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '123456'),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'port'     => env('DB_PORT', '7373'),
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'cp_bn',
    ],
```

Here you can see i have specified schema, but i want it to be Dynamic. The schema name  will come from client side.

I am currently doing like following

```
  $connection =DB::connection()->getPdo();
  $connection->prepare("Set search_path to {$schema}")->execute();
```

But in this case i have to execute this whenever the connection to the database is made. I need to save it globally for all connection once it is set.